# Google Tag Manager - document.getElementById and document.querySelector not returning value until element is inspected

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-tag-manager

I can find similar threads to what I'm asking, but they're very old and don't seem to provide a solution.

I'm working with Google Tag Manager and Helpscout, and I am trying to retrieve text (title) values via getElementById and querySelector.

The Helpscout "Beacon" is embedded via an iframe, which I am sure is the root cause of the challenge. However, I've been able to successfully implement an event listener based on [this guidance](https://dumbdata.co/listeners/helpscout-chat-event-listener/) and by utilising an "Element Visibility" trigger targeting the iframe insertion with the selection method of CSS selector.

(fwiw, that is `iframe[id][data-cy='FrameComponent'][aria-label='Toggle Customer Support']`)

However, when I try to retrieve H1 values, for example, in Custom Javascript values they are always blank.

If I test the Custom JS variable code directly in Chrome Console on initial page load they also fail, but if I inspect ANY part of the Helpscout beacon and re-run the code, a value is returned.

My question is, is there a way to have GTM re-evaluate the content of the page to return these values that I'm not thinking of?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621540/document-queryselector-returns-null-until-element-is-inspected-using-devtools#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20comment-,0,it%20helps%20anyone%2C%20I%20solved%20it%20by%20accessing%20the%20frame%20by,-window.frames%5B) seemed like what would work, except for some reason now I can't even see the iframe id that I mentioned above for the Element Visibility trigger despite the fact the tag it is linked to is still working!

Chat GPT (yeah, sorry....) suggested requestAnimationFrame but that doesn't work. Neither does setTimeout.

Here's some code that hasn't worked so far.

`function getArticleName() {
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
var titleElement = document.getElementById("article-modal-header");
var articleName = titleElement ? (titleElement.textContent || titleElement.innerText) : "";

```
if (articleName === "") {
  titleElement = document.querySelector('div[data-cy="Heading"]');
  if (titleElement) {
    articleName = titleElement.getAttribute('title') || '';
  }
}0

// Now 'articleName' contains the retrieved title value
console.log('Article Name:', articleName);

return articleName;
```

});
}`